# CheckBoxList OnDataBound and setting checked boxes for form submission

Tags: javascript, .net, validation

I am using C# .Net and have nearly completed the coding to use an OnDataBound for a CheckBoxList to check boxes upon form load in a web form.  In the Page_Load a List<> is populated that contains the checked values.  I then loop through the list in the OnDataBound event to check the appropriate boxes.  This all works fine and I can provide additional code if necessary.
Once the form is loaded I can see everything is checked as expected but when I try to submit the form, my validation is indicating that the box is not checked.

My validation is in Javascript and is using the .checked property, i.e. `if (cbx.checked)` ...
In the code-behind I am using a loop similar to the following to check the values when appropriate:

```
  foreach (ListItem item in cbList.Items)
  {
      if (Areas.Contains(item.ToString()))
      {
          item.Selected = true;
      }
  }
```

It seems there is a discrepancy between the .Selected and .checked properties or is there something more basic than this?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Could you show me some code for the "Areas" that you're using the contains method on? What type is it?

Comment: are you checking for `!IsPostBack` before you bind the checkbox list, or binding every time `Page_Load` is called?

Answer (score 0):

Is the function performed on submit a server side or client side method?

I think what is happening is that the Web Page is posting back on submit so your JavaScript isn't in the picture until the page has reloaded. I don't think that the JavaScript will do the validation after a server side onSubmitEvent is initiated until the page has reloaded.